# Aria-label on div styled as image

Tags: html, wai-aria, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

In table cell I have a `<span>` element, that is styled as image and displays state of interface (Enabled/Disabled/Error), based on it's color.

For users with proper vision, it is compact and understandable. I don't want to change it. But as there is no text in this span, it is not read by screen reader. (understandable, but problem)

What is the correct approach to handle such elements for screen readers?

---

Expected solution would be to add aria-label with text for screen reader, but, as I found in other topics, "aria-label does not work on `<div>` nor `<span>`". As I tested it on JAWS 15, it is true, but in JAWS 18 such labels are being read just fine (why?).

Also I tried to add `role="img"` to this span, and to add text in `aria-label` and/or `alt` and/or `title` with no result in JAWS 15.

Comment: what about aria-labelledby?

Comment: @DeepuReghunath It works in same way as aria-label. (I tested it on JAWS 15 to be sure). And again it should not be supported for <div> and <span> elements.

Comment: Is it not possible for you to add the correct markup for this (i.e., an `img` with `alt`)?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "normal users"?  Are you talking about sighted users compared to low-vision users?  The latter are normal users too.

For low-vision users, yes, an `aria-label` is normally the way to go.  Thank you for considering accessibility issues.

But you'll also have an issue for color deficient users.  Those that can't distinguish between certain colors.  Is color the only means for conveying the state of the object?  Is there an associated icon too?  Color-deficient users won't be using a screen reader so won't benefit from an `aria-label`.

It's not clear in the html or aria specs on the default role of a `<span>`.  The `aria-label` should be used in the [accessible name calculation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2) and step 2D says only if the element is presentational (meaning `role='presentation'` or `role='none'`) should the aria-label be ignored.  So, if a `<span>` is considered presentational, then its `aria-label` will be ignored.  JAWS seems to be interpreting it this way but NVDA does not.  NVDA in firefox will read the `aria-label` of a `<span>`.

So your best choice might be to give the `<span>` a role, such as `role='img'` or `role='note'`, so that you can give it an `aria-label` too, but that will also cause the role of the span to be announced.

Or as one commented above, use a real `<img>` with `alt` text.

Comment: "Normal users" - my bad on using the term like that, I will update it. For color deficient users there is separate theme with high contrast colors - they are covered as well. As for `role='img'` - it unfortunately is not working. Maybe I will go with last suggestion - to go with `<img>` tags. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: Can you elaborate what's "not working" with `role='img'`?  Just to confirm the obvious, did you use `img` or `image`,  The former is correct.  Using `<img>` or `role='img'` should be the exact same thing from a screen reader perspective.  Both should work.  I'm just curious why it doesn't work.  A `<div>` or `<span>` does not have a role by default so adding an `aria-label` to them doesn't really do anything.  If you specify a role on them, then the label should be read.